# Error message in simple selenium code

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to learn selenium. So I installed the below tools:

- Firefox V 31
- Selenium-firefox-driver-2.0b3

And I used the code below to run it and got a error message. Not sure what it means. Any help will be good.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Sele {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create webDriver reference
    WebDriver driver;

    // Launch FirefoxDriver
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Open the web page
    driver.get("http://google.com");

    // Enter the text in the search box
    WebElement searchText = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchText.sendKeys("FirefoxDriver");

    // Close the driver
    driver.quit();

}

}
```

Error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       org/openqa/selenium/RenderedWebElement
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at Sele.main(Sele.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.openqa.selenium.RenderedWebElement
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have a dependency missing as explained on their main [site](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) you need to install the selenium server as well not just the browser driver.

Comment: Yes I have installed "selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar" as well. Yet the same error is there

Comment: The `selenium-server` is used to run script remotely, you need `selenium-java`

Comment: Yes I installed "selenium-java-2.44.0.jar". Still the same error

Comment: I'm stuck with this issue..any help? :(